# parsing a string using string tokenizer twice

Tags: java, regex, string

I am getting  input string as below from some procedure

> ```
> service:jmx:t3://10.20.30.40:9031/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
> ```

I want to parse it in java  and get out

```
t3
10.20.30.40
9031
```

into separate strings
I think I can use string tokenizer   but I have to tokenize 2 times ?Any better way to handle this?

Comment: Yes, Regular expressions!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [JMXServiceUrl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXServiceURL.html) class. It will parse the URL for you. No need to battle with regex or `String` splits.

```
String url = "service:jmx:t3://10.20.30.40:9031/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime";
JMXServiceURL jmxServiceURL = new JMXServiceURL(url);
System.out.println(jmxServiceURL.getHost());
System.out.println(jmxServiceURL.getPort());
System.out.println(jmxServiceURL.getProtocol());
```

**Prints**

```
10.20.30.40
9031
t3
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a somehow composed String and you can ignorie performance, I would prefer a readable solution (more than regex ;-)) like this:

```
int pos_1 = input.indexOf("//");

String s1 = input.substring(0, pos_1);
String input_2 = input.substring(pos_1 + 2);

int pos_2 = input_2.indexOf(":");
String s2 = input_2.substring(0, pos_2);
...
```

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: It is possible, that it is very personal to me, but I always have to read docs when using regex. But I always need it all 10 month or so ;-) To me it really depends on the specific use-case and environment. No doubt: RegEx seems more professional!

Comment: I'd go with Deepak Bala, if it's allways an URL.

Comment: Depends on how much performance you may loose. And what I really meant was, that other solution may be faster (but must not). This depends heavenly on the sum of performed parses.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a good approach. You should find the pattern for your string and group with parenthesis what you want. Maybe this could be enough for you:
`service\\:jmx\\:(?<groupName01>[a-z0-9]+)\\://(?<groupName02>[0-9\\.]+)\\:(?<groupName03>[o-9]+)`

See [Java Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

If you use java earlier from 7, do not use `?<groupName>` in the pattern. It will be grouped by number.

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple string split

```
    String s = "service:jmx:t3://10.20.30.40:9031/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime";
    String tokens[] = s.split("[:/]");
    System.out.println(tokens[2]);
    System.out.println(tokens[5]);
    System.out.println(tokens[6]);
```